# Рисование в андроид

Tags: android, canvas

Необходимо реализовать рисование по экрану. Аналогично кисти в виндовском поинте. Т.е мы зажали палец на экране и водим, за ним рисуется линия, отпустили - перестала. Полный аналог рисования кисти в поинте. Есть идеи как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApiDemos -> TouchPaint смотрите

Comment: Как очищать экран от нарисованого?

Comment: очень просто - нарисовать большой прямоугольник на весь экран:)

Comment: Не поверите! Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

Answer (score 0):

[Вот тут](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2011/08/android.html) описан пример создание простой рисовалки для Android